# Is there any tool for fast exporting to unreal engine 4?

Tags: game-engine, export, texture-baking, external-applications, unreal-engine

In Zbrush you can with one click: generate normals, UVs, make mesh low poly,bake texture and save all of these to files. So only thing is left to import those files to engine. Is there some plugin for same function in blender? It lacks of some preferences,but its ideal for indie developer. Is it possible in blender?

Comment: You're looking for a python code by the sounds of it